# Time/space traveling story where a person travels through a portal in the London Underground

Tags: story-identification

So, I read this story (novel/book) a while ago, but now cannot remember the name. Here is the synopsis, as I remember it (please note that my memory could be faulty):

The story begins in London, where two brothers are having an argument, over a girl. Somehow one enters through a portal that opens up in the London Underground. The other eventually follows him, but because the Portals transport through Space/Time, his brother is now a successful interstellar trader (the following brother does not yet know this). The main conflict at this point is the sentient red cloud (that I can't remember the name of) that is encroaching on the area where these people are hanging out,  which is called The Gnarl. Eventually it is figured out that the Gnarl is really an ancient weapon called "The Torch" that only the other brother can operate. The cloud is beaten back, and... That's as much as I can remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The novel is *The Recollection* by Gareth L. Powell.  Partial synopsis lifted from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/190751998X):

> When his brother disappears into a bizarre gateway on a London Underground escalator, failed artist Ed Rico and his brother's wife Alice have to put aside their feelings for each other to go and find him. Their quest through the 'arches' will send them hurtling through time, to new and terrifying alien worlds.

[image: Cover of "The Recollection". The cover shows a metallic object entering the atmosphere above a planet, against a starry background.]

Comment: You're welcome.  Your description had enough odd details that I found the book with a Google Books search.  Google has scanned an enormous number of books and magazines, so if you can remember proper names, particularly odd ones like "the Gnarl" and "the Torch", you can't go wrong by trying Google first.

Comment: Well, hooray for monolithic corporations. And I'll be sure to try that next time. Many thanks, again.